# SDK Evernote PHP - Search for notes only within a given stack

Tags: evernote

I am using the evernote API to search for notes. I would like to know how to search for the notes only within a given stack.

At the moment I have the code below:

```
$client = new \Evernote\Client(config('app.evernote_token'), false);

$search = new \Evernote\Model\Search('ftp');
$notebook = null;
$scope = \Evernote\Client::SEARCH_SCOPE_NONE;
$order = \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_REVERSE | \Evernote\Client::SORT_ORDER_RECENTLY_CREATED;
$maxResult = 50;

$results = $client->findNotesWithSearch($search, $notebook, $scope, $order, 
$maxResult);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved as follows:

```
$search = new \Evernote\Model\Search('stack:"Palavra-chave"');
```